# Manage content and structure is missing from Site Actions Menu items in 2010

Tags: site-collection

My menu item "Manage Content and Structure " is not present in the Site Actions Menu, after some google research i found that there are 2 features that need to be activated for this item to show up. I clearly activated them, SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure in site collection features and SharePoint Server Publishing in manage site features.
Anybody else has another idea what other dependancies are needed?

Comment: Just to check - Can you find the Pages library, now that you activated the Features? Are you aware of any Custom Actions (custom developments) that are hiding menu items??

Comment: there is no custum actions on for hiding menu items. But for new sites we disabled and left only the custum sites. Maybe this can be an issue.

Comment: okay there is one hidding the CreatePublishingPage

Comment: Ok, it might be that one hiding more menu items?